# Do any open source Android ROMs work on smart clocks?

Tags: lineageos, android-things

Has LineageOS or any other open source Android ROM moved into the Smart Clock (bedside alarm clock space)?

It seems [some of these run Android Things](https://www.cnet.com/reviews/google-assistant-and-a-touchscreen-help-make-a-better-alarm-clock-review/):

> The touchscreen isn't as robust as Google's other smart displays, but **it uses the same Android Things software which is a trimmed-down version of Google's mobile operating system meant for smart home gadgets.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the Lenovo Smart Clock [open source software is here](https://smartsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/smart/smart-home/smart-clock/za4r/downloads/ds539701).  Looking quickly it appears to be the kernel only.

The device's SoC appears to from MediaTek, codename `mt8167s`  possibly the same device powering the Lenovo Smart Display.  (The kernel config file is called `mt8167s_ref_debug_defconfig`).  I don't see any device repositories on github for this, but interestingly, there is a [file](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/boards/mt8167s_ref.gni) for Google's Fuchsia OS Zircon microkernel for this board.

Somoene appears to have put [the source on github here](https://github.com/deadman96385/android_kernel_lenovo_mt8167s).  He (I assume "he"- the name is "deadman96385") has a TWRP recovery repo [here](https://github.com/deadman96385/twrp_device_lenovo_cube) for the smart clock (which may actually be named `iot_mt8167s_som` ??) which might be a good starting point for doing a full android port.

Also, looks like he dumped the rom [here](https://github.com/deadman96385/things_mt8167s_som_dump).